# SqlAlchemy error while connecting to engine using python 3.7.7

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

When I create an engine and try to connect to database it throws an error:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry

engine = db.create_engine(<connectionstring>)
connection = engine.connect()
```

Output:

```
val = self._isolation_levels_returned[res]
KeyError: '\x02'
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: @Sergey Shubin  any inputs for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Environment issues from my end. Now no issues.